# Schema serialization with annotations also serialized

Tags: java, json, jackson, avro, thrift-protocol

We want to serialize schema for Java classes such that all the annotations present on any field or class is also serialized into the schema.

I have found no tool that does that.

Avro does not handle non-string map keys and FasterXML does not handle cyclic references.
And both of them do not serialize annotations into the schema.

Is there any Java JSON (de)serializer that does this?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Thrift supports complex map keys in most languages and has fairly wide support for JSON serialization. Type cycles (self-referential types, etc.) were recently introduced and have not yet been released or implemented in a wide array of languages. That said there appears to be a strong commitment to bringing this capability to a high state of polish in the near term.

Something like the following will work using the C++ dev trunk today.

```
struct tree {
   1: tree left (cpp.ref="")
   2: tree right (cpp.ref="")
}

service simple {
   void hello(1: string msg, 2: tree t)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays [Jackson JSON Schema Module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema) supports cyclic dependencies. Here is an example that works for version 2.4.1:

```
public class JacksonSchemaCyclic {
    public static class Bean {
        @JsonPropertyDescription("This is a property description")
        public String anExample;
        public int anInt;
        public Bean aBean;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
        mapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(Bean.class, visitor);
        JsonSchema jsonSchema = visitor.finalSchema();
        System.out.println(mapper
                .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonSchema));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "id" : "urn:jsonschema:stackoverflow:JacksonSchemaCyclic:Bean",
  "properties" : {
    "aBean" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "$ref" : "urn:jsonschema:stackoverflow:JacksonSchemaCyclic:Bean"
    },
    "anInt" : {
      "type" : "integer"
    },
    "anExample" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "description" : "This is a property description"
    }
  }
}
```